# Looping rows to plot lines between couples of coordinates in Python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm kind of new to Python and I'm struggling to make the following plot using matplotlib:

[image: ![enter image description here]

With the following data:

[image]

I have many rows, so I was thinking to do something like:

```
For each row, plot a line from (x_start, y_start) to (x_end, y_end)
```

Any advise?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you been able to load your data in Python yet?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Import the data via something like `pandas.read_csv()`. Here, I just put everything into an array to make this simple.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: x = np.array([[1, 1, 3, 1], [2, 2, 4, 2], [3, 3, 5, 3], [4, 4, 6, 4], [5, 5, 7, 5]])

In [4]: plt.figure()
   ...: for row in x:
   ...:     plt.plot([row[0], row[2]], [row[1], row[3]], marker='.')
   ...:

In [5]: plt.show()
```

[image]

I leave the axis labels and the colors to you. Hint: look into matplotlib's colormaps.

Comment: How would you address it if the 4 coordinates are columns of a DataFrame with hundreds of lines. I guess np.array is not translating to DataFrame in my head.

Comment: One of two ways: either use `pd.DataFrame.iterrows()` to loop through the rows, or call `df.values` to get a numpy array representation of your DataFrame. The underlying data structure of a DataFrame is just a numpy array!